# How to copy files from host to docker named volume

Tags: django, docker

I started a Django app with docker with bind host to handle user uploads but now I want to migrate to named volumes but I already have files in my host, so I was wonderings how can I copy the files from the host to the volume, this is my docker-compose for my web container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    restart: always
    image: "postgres:13.2-alpine"
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  web:
      container_name: web
      restart: always
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./docker/development/Dockerfile
      environment:
        DEBUG: 'true'
        DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: myapp.app_settings.development
      command: sh ./docker/development/runserver.sh
      ports:
        - "8000:8000"
      env_file:
        - ./.env.dev
      volumes:
        - .:/app # Enable code reload
        - django-static:/app/run/static
        - django-media:/app/run/media
      depends_on:
        - db

volumes:
  django-static:
  django-media:
```

And this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
# COPY . /app
ADD . /app

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt install -y netcat

COPY ./docker/development/entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

There is a way to copy my uploads from host: /home/art/myapp/run/media and /home/art/myapp/run/static to volumes django-static and django-media ?

Also, How I can backup the files from the volume?

Comment: You can use `docker cp` to copy files from your host to a named volume mounted inside a container. You can also use `docker cp` in the other direction, to copy files out of your container to your host.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give me an example with my configurations? Please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make it this way:

```
docker run -d --rm --name temp -v django-media:/root alpine tail -f /dev/null
docker cp ./run/media/. temp:/root 
docker stop temp
docker exec -it --user root web /bin/bash
chown -R root:root /run/media
```

Creates a temp container with named volume mounted

```
docker run -d --rm --name temp -v django-media:/root alpine tail -f /dev/null
```

Then copy all files to temp container volume (./run/media/. copy all  the files/folders inside to target dir /root)

```
docker cp ./run/media/. temp:/root
```

then stops the temp container

```
docker stop temp
```

Now files are copied but without right permissions, exec a terminal inside the container that mounts the named volume, move to directory and run chown to own the copied files, in this case I asume that files inside container belongs to root:root and the files copied belongs to different user, you can check that with ls -la command.

```
docker exec -it --user root web /bin/bash
chown -R root:root /run/media
```

Comment: Instead of `tail -f /dev/null` you could write `sleep infinity` to make it easier to understand.